# Hibernate metadata for uniqueness

Tags: java, hibernate, metadata

I'm trying to fetch as much metadata as possible from hibernate, and I'm struggling with a few constraints, like uniqueness.

I have been trying to use:

```
AbstractEntityPersister metadata = (AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata( clazz );
boolean[] uniqueness = metadata.getPropertyUniqueness();
```

But it seems the the uniqueness array is always saying `false` for all properties, I'm also using the `EntityPersister` to fetch nullability (`getPropertyNullability`) and it is working fine.

Any ideas?

(I'm using HBM btw, if it matters. Almost tempted to resort to parsing the HBM files directly, but seems like a very ugly solution).

Comment: Just to be sure, you're getting propertyUniqueness false for `<property name="foo" unique="true" />` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear. I'm getting an array the size of propertiesNames.length, but all the values are false.

Comment: Have you created the database using this XML configuration? Because if an existing DB doesn't contain uniqueness, merely this config will not alter the situation at runtime. The `unique="true"` setting will only have an effect when it actually creates the DB from it.

Comment: Yes, several properties in the database have ```UNIQUE CONSTRAINT``` on them. I think the issue is as you said, ```getPropertyUniqueness```is not actually what I should use.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look in the source for AbstractEntityPersister. Seems like this is filled like this:

```
propertyUniqueness[i] = prop.getValue().isAlternateUniqueKey();
```

which seems to indicate the "getPropertyUniqueness" would be more appropriately named "getAlternateUniqueKey".
Likely, `getPropertyUniqueness` will return true only for

```
unique-key="true"
```

and not for

```
unique="true"
```

in your `hbm.xml`.

Comment: Oh, if that's the case, then yes.. this is not what I'm looking for. Question then becomes, is it possible to get this information somehow.

Comment: I don't know another way with hbm.xml configuration. With JPA-style annotations (`@Entity`, `@OneToMany` etc) you could use Reflection to analyze the annotations at runtime. `@Column(unique = true)`

Comment: @geert3 may you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?